# Вопрос про энкодеры php кода

Tags: php, шифрование

В простейшем случае энкодер работает так:

1. Получает после компиляции скрипта массив оп-кодов
2. Сохраняет оп-коды файл.
3. php extension восстанавливает из файла оп-коды и отдаёт их на выполнение zend_execute.

Вопрос такой: имеет ли смысл шифровать этот массив оп-кодов перед записью в файл?

Я прочёл много информации по этому вопросу и часто писали, что шифрование желательно. Но какой в нем смысл, когда можно легко хукнуть функцию zend_execute и перехватить оп-коды после того, как они расшифруются экстеншионом?

Answer (score 1):

Смысл в том, что злоумышленник, получивший доступ к файлу с кодами, не обязательно получит доступ к расширению php.

Процесс, в котором работает php, обязан иметь доступ к своему же файлу с опкодами. Поэтому опкоды можно украсть через какую-нибудь инъекцию. Но можно настроить сервер таким образом, чтобы процесс, в котором запущен php, не имел доступа к своим же бинарникам. Если такая настройка выполнена, то шифрование опкодов имеет смысл.